# Cloning a table into a separate schema in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, schema, insert

On an SQL Server database that I manage, there are a fair number of backup clone tables lying around, littered throughout the `dbo` schema. I am about to create such a backup clone now, and I would like to clean the main schema up by creating this new clone in a schema called `backups` and moving all the existing clones there as well. Backups do not need to include foreign keys, just data.

Through Azure Data Studio, I logged in with an administrator account and did `CREATE SCHEMA backups` to create the new schema. I’ve since verified that I can `CREATE TABLE backups.new_table` and `SELECT * FROM backups.new_table`, so I should have the necessary permissions.

However, when I try to clone a table from the default schema to the new one, I can’t. The way I’m trying to do it is how I’ve seen it done in lots of answers on Q&A sites, such as [the accepted answer to this question on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/788575/copy-table-from-another-schema) (except to a differently-named schema in the same DB, not to an identically-named schema in a different DB):

```
INSERT INTO [db].[backups].[table_2022] SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
```

That gives me this error (with or without specifying the database name first, same result):

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid object name 'backups.table_2022'.

Why is that? If I can `CREATE TABLE backups.new_table` and `INSERT INTO dbo.new_table` as well, then why not `INSERT INTO backups.new_table`?

Short of manually recreating the structure of all tables I need to clone and then inserting the data, how can I clone tables from the default schema to a different schema?

Comment: The article you link to does `select * into <target table>...`, not `insert into <target table>...` like you do; I hope you can spot the difference.

Comment: @mustaccio Wow… reading comprehension fail here. To be fair, I’ve gone through about a dozen such answers, and I copied the `INSERT INTO` query out from one or another of them, so I got it from somewhere, but that is still such a dumb mistake. Thank you for unfogging my mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load a backup table without first creating the table schema you would need to use [select into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) syntax

```
SELECT * INTO [db].[backups].[table_2022] FROM [db].[dbo].[table];
```

Comment: I hope that, if I hadn’t been so tired and cross-eyed, I would have noticed that the answer I linked to actually uses `SELECT INTO` not `INSERT INTO`. But I didn’t. I got the `INSERT INTO` variant from some other answer I’d come across while Googling, and then just didn’t notice the other answers I came across were similar, but crucially different. Thank you!